# Oracle SQL : Why my prompt is repeat and repeat

Tags: sql, oracle, infinite-loop, sqlplus

```
Enter the year you would like to check >2022
Enter the Tour Guide ID you would like to check >TG02
 72
 73
 74
 75
 76
```

This is the output of the screen

```sql
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';


Undefine v_guideID, v_year

set linesize 75
set pagesize 40

ACCEPT v_year PROMPT 'Enter the year you would like to check >'
ACCEPT v_guideID PROMPT 'Enter the Tour Guide ID you would like to check >'

DECLARE
   v_year number;
   lastdayofyear date;
BEGIN
   lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_year, 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
END;

COL tourguideid FORMAT A8 HEADING "Guide ID"
COL type FORMAT A5 HEADING "Type"
COL name FORMAT A20 HEADING "Name"
COL datejoined FORMAT A14 HEADING "Join Date" 
COL basicsalary FORMAT $9999 HEADING "Basic Salary per Month"
COL Allowance FORMAT $99999 HEADING "Allowance Amount"
COL ProfitSharing FORMAT $99999 HEADING "Annual Profit Shared"
COL totalsalary FORMAT $99999999 HEADING "Annual Salary"

TTITLE center 'Annual Salary for ' &v_guideID ' in ' &v_year -
RIGHT 'Page No: ' FORMAT 999 SQL.PNO SKIP 2
BREAK ON tourguideid SKIP 2 ON bookingid
COMPUTE SUM LABEL 'Total : ' OF Allowance ON tourguideid;



create or replace view GetEachTourGuideMonth as (select TG.tourguideid, (months_between(TG.datejoined, lastDayOfYear)) as WorkMonths
from tourguide TG);

create or replace view TotalMonth as 
select SUM(WorkMonths)
From GetEachTourGuideMonth;

create or replace view ProfitUnit as 
Select tourguideid, name, (case v_year when 2021 then
                        (case when WorkMonths >= 12 then 0.03
                                   when WorkMonths >= 3 then 0.005
                                   else 0
                           END)
                        when 2022 then
                        (case when WorkMonths >= 12 then 0.0228
                                   when WorkMonths >= 3 then 0.005
                                   else 0
                           END)
                        when 2023 then
                        (case when WorkMonths >= 12 then 0.0188
                                   when WorkMonths >= 3 then 0.005
                                   else 0
                           END) 
             END)ProfitRate * PS.SharedProfit as ProfitGiven
From tourguide TG
JOIN ProfitSharing PS ON TG.tourguideid = PS.tourguideid;

create or replace view AllowanceEachGuide as 
SELECT
    COALESCE(P.tourguideid, CP.tourguideid) AS tourguideid,
    COALESCE(P.Allowance, CP.Allowance) AS Allowance
FROM
    Package P
FULL OUTER JOIN
    CustomizedPackage CP
ON
    P.tourguideid = CP.tourguideid
AND
    P.Allowance = CP.Allowance;

Select TG.tourguideid, TG.type ,TG.name, TG.datejoined, TG.basicsalary, AEG.Allowance, PU.ProfitSharing, (PU.ProfitGiven + (TG.basicsalary * 12) + AEG.Allowance) as TotalSalary
From tourguide TG
JOIN
    ProfitUnit PU ON TG.tourguideid = PU.tourguideid
JOIN
    AllowanceEachGuide AEG ON TG.tourguideid = AEG.tourguideid
where TG.tourguideid = &v_guideID;
```

These are the code. This file is calculating the salary of each tour guide and the profit overall is okay. But this file have the infinite input problem...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're missing a **slash** character at the end of PL/SQL anonymous block; see line `#7`:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL> Undefine v_guideID, v_year
SQL>
SQL> set linesize 75
SQL> set pagesize 40
SQL>
SQL> ACCEPT v_year PROMPT 'Enter the year you would like to check >'
Enter the year you would like to check >2023
SQL> ACCEPT v_guideID PROMPT 'Enter the Tour Guide ID you would like to check >'
Enter the Tour Guide ID you would like to check >225
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_year number;
  3     lastdayofyear date;
  4  BEGIN
  5     lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_year, 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
  6  END;
  7  /                                                                --> here
```

Code is now executed, but - incorrectly:

```
   lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_year, 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
                   *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

What's wrong with date format? There's no `MMM`! "DEC" you used suggests that you, actually, want `MON` format model, so - let's change it:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_year number;
  3     lastdayofyear date;
  4  BEGIN
  5     lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  6  END;
  7  /
   lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
                   *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

What's wrong with month now? Aha ... my database doesn't speak English but Croatian, so I'll have to fix that first. Alternatively - and what might be a better choice - is to use code that doesn't depend on NLS. For example, you chould have chosen `31.12.`.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_year number;
  3     lastdayofyear date;
  4  BEGIN
  5     lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  6  END;
  7  /
   lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
                   *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Gee, what now?! It is about `v_year`. It is a **local variable** (declared in this PL/SQL block), not the one whose value you *accepted* at the beginning of the script. So: remove it from declaration section (it is useless) and include ampersand `&` character in front of it, i.e. use a **substitution variable**:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     lastdayofyear date;
  3  BEGIN
  4     lastdayofyear := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || &v_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Right; not it is OK and code can go on:

```
SQL> COL tourguideid FORMAT A8 HEADING "Guide ID"
SQL> COL type FORMAT A5 HEADING "Type"
SQL> ...
```

Not for long, though, as it seems that view uses variable whose value you calculated in that PL/SQL procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace view GetEachTourGuideMonth as (select lastdayofyear from dual);
create or replace view GetEachTourGuideMonth as (select lastdayofyear from dual)
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "LASTDAYOFYEAR": invalid identifier
```

Sure it can't work; that's not visible at SQL level; no use of it.

You could create view *dynamically*:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str varchar2(500);
  3  BEGIN
  4     l_str := 'create or replace view GetEachTourGuideMonth as ' ||
  5              q'[select TO_DATE('31.12.&v_year', 'DD.MM.YYYY') ]' ||
  6              ' as last_day_of_year from dual';
  7    execute immediate l_str;
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From GetEachTourGuideMonth;

LAST_DAY_O
----------
31/12/2023

SQL>
```

Or, at SQL level, but this time use `v_year` with appropriate modifications:

```
SQL> create or replace view GetEachTourGuideMonth as
  2    select add_months(trunc(to_date(&v_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'), 12) - 1 as last_day_of_year
  3    from dual;

View created.

SQL> select * From GetEachTourGuideMonth;

LAST_DAY_O
----------
31/12/2023
```

I don't have tables you later use so I won't debug your code any more. Just note that - as you re-use `v_year` thoughout that code, you'll have to precede it with ampersand. But, not just one - use **two** of them: `&&v_year` because - if you don't - you'll be asked to re-enter that value every time you reference it. Don't forget to `undefine v_year` to *initialize* it.

---

Therefore, not every trivial code is as trivial as you thought. There might be things you have to pay attention to if you want that code to work properly.